# Linux integration into Active Directory (Cross domain)

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap, debian, nss

I am trying to test a solution of integrating my Debian 6 Squeeze machine in an Active Directory domain.

I dit it with libnss-ldap.conf & ldap.conf

Now, I want to authenticate other users from different domain which I manage. Can you give me the solution?

I tried Global Catalog by adding a new line in ldap.conf with the port number 3268 but it isn't work. There is someone who can help me to do this.

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Are you using samba at all?

Is mapping of specific uid/gid to users important? What is the OS of the active directory server? Are you planning to use UNIX components for Windows?

(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731178.aspx)

If so configure your samba.cfg shown here.

```
  "[global]
   realm = WORKGROUP
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   security = ADS
   winbind enum users = Yes
   winbind enum groups = Yes
   idmap config WORKGROUP:backend = ad
   idmap config WORKGROUP:range = 20000-40000000
   idmap config WORKGROUP:schema_mode = rfc2307
   winbind nss info = rfc2307
   winbind expand groups = 2
   winbind nested groups = yes
   winbind use default domain = Yes
   idmap gid = 10000-20000
   idmap uid = 10000-20000
   kerberos method = secrets and keytab
   template homedir = /home/%D/%U
   template shell = /bin/bash
   usershare allow guests = No
   winbind refresh tickets = yes"
```

Once your samba config is set are you using authconfig to attach to the active directory server?

Options for authconfig use only the ones you need

```
"authconfig  
--update  
--kickstart  
--enablewinbind  
--enablewinbindauth  
--smbsecurity=ads  
--smbworkgroup=$ADSWorkgroup  
--smbrealm=$ADSDomain  
--smbservers=$ADSServer 
--winbindjoin=$AdminUser 
--winbindtemplatehomedir=/home/%U 
--winbindtemplateshell=/bin/bash 
--enablewinbindusedefaultdomain 
--enablelocauthorize"
```

Comment: I tried using the ctrl+k method to put code in, but it just wouldn't take hence the line spacing.